# Read PostgreSQL Bytea column in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am trying to read a `bytea` column from PostgreSQL using Ruby.
The problem is that it returns the hex encoded string of the `bytea` value.
I would like it to return exactly the same as if I would open a binary file with the same content with `File.read()`.

The following gives me the hex encoded value:

```
require 'pg'

conn = PG.connect(...)
res  = conn.exec('SELECT bytea_column FROM some_table')
res.each do |r|
    raw = r['bytea_column']
    puts "#{raw}"
end
```

I think I need to use `PG::TextDecoder::Bytea` to decode the `bytea` column correctly. Is this correct? And if so, how exactly is it supposed to be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks everyone but I figured it out. The answer is `PG::Connection.unescape_bytea`:

```
require 'pg'

conn = PG.connect(...)
res  = conn.exec('SELECT bytea_column FROM some_table')  
res.each do |r|
    raw = r['bytea_column']
    binary_data = PG::Connection.unescape_bytea(raw)
    puts "#{binary_data}"
end
```

Comment: One thing to avoid in Ruby is doing `"#{x}"` instead of `x`. There's no reason to surround something in quotes like that. `puts` will convert to a string if it feels it's necessary.